# A timer with c# console

Tags: c#, timer, console

I'm using c# console . I have a timer like : `int TimeElasped = 0`  to show and update times .
it can resolve with a `for( ; ; )`

but computer cant do other codes !!!
so I am using this code :

```
using System.Threading;


public class Test
{
    static int TimeElasped = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       Timer tm = new Timer(tm_tick,null,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
       Console.Write("");
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void tm_tick(object obj)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Timer:{0}", TimeElasped );
        Counter++;
    }
}
```

I Cannot use `Console.Clear()` because it clear all data in console , when I remove `Console.Clear()` timer is showing line by line !!!

so how can I have a timer that update time ?

thanks ,

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.  You may be looking for `Console.CursorPosition`.

Comment: The standard trick is Console.Write("\rTime:{0}", TimeElapsed);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the time as it ticks in a console, you will need to clear the window and "redraw" everything with the updated time:

```
static void tm_tick(object obj)
    {   
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("===========================================================================");
        Console.WriteLine("Bunch of stuff here to look pretty");        
        Console.WriteLine("===========================================================================");
        Console.WriteLine("");        
        Console.WriteLine("Timer:{0}", TimeElasped );
        Counter++;
    }
```

However this is based on your initial question, where I can only presume that you are trying to have just the time change and nothing else.